# Retaining usage rights in the pdfs

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to populate interactive pdf form with the xml using itext:

```
 //build the xmlString, convert it to InputStream
 AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.getAcrofields();
 XfaForm form = fields.getXfa();
 form.fillXfaForm(xmlStream);
```

The fields getting populated, however the resulting *.pdf is now not editable in the Adobe Reader. That is the document property has "Filling of form fields: Now Allowed" now. So, I was digging around for a solution and read somewhere (I believe the itext in action book), that the itext does, indeed, break the usage rights. After, I tried the solutions described here:
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=166

That is, remove usage rights completely or create stamper in the append mode, e.g.,

```
reader.removeUsageRights();
```

or

```
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), '\0', true)
```

The pdf is now editable. However, the PDF form I am populating has a drop-down menu - if a particular option in that drop-down is selected, the pdf form activates one of its own text field. This does not work anymore - the drop-down is selected, but the text field it supposed to activate remains inactivate and blank.

I've read that the usage rights are part of the pdf own encryption, I was wondering if it is possible to get that encryption and set it into into a populated copy of the pdf form?

Thank you

Comment: *I've read that the usage rights are part of the pdf own encryption* - permissions are but you indeed require usage rights which are governed by usage right signatures. And only Adobe products have the private key to apply them.

Comment: Moreover, some XFA forms (not all) have some secret sauce involving a hash value. If the form is changed and the hash value isn't, you get the described behavior. No spec describes how the hash is created. We've tried many combinations, but only Adobe knows which data is actually used to create the hash. Changing the form so that it doesn't depend on that hash value is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks guys, curious - is there a way to change perhaps the pdf form itself, with Adobe Pro, as a workaround?

Comment: If the form has been created in LiveCycle Designer, you will need LCD to modify it; Acrobat can not do much with such forms. That also means that you have to watch out how your PDF has been created.